# How do you solve $y=ax^2-ax+b$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I have the polynomial $y = ax^2 - ax + b$, where I can find $y$ given that I know $a$, $b$, and $x$.

How can I transform this polynomial to give me $x$ when I know $a$, $b$, and $y$?

Comment: Solve $ax^2-ax+b-y=0$ for $x$, which is a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: Brilliantly simple. Not sure how it escaped my thinking. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion in the comments, $$x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4a(b-y)}}{2a}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ax^2-ax+(b-y)=0$$

$$x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4a(b-y)}}{2a}\,.$$

Only when a≠0